# undefined jQuery object when it should be

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to change the color of a background using jQuery. I've made an array with color names and their value.

If I do

```
console.log(colorValue);
```

I get the classname I want to use to find the corresponding color, when I do

```
console.log(colorArr.colorValue);
```

I get an undefined, but when I do

```
console.log(colorArr.red);
```

I get the corresponding color:

```
function colorChange(){
    $('div.colorpicker ul li a').on('click', function() {
        var colorArr = {'greenyellow': '#d2db46', 'lightgreen': '#8dc13f', 'darkgreen': '#56a174', 'blauw' : '#3199d1', 'darkblue':'#326b9b', 'darkpurple':'#584586' , 'purple':'#985494', 'red':'#ca4538', 'orange' : '#e27a37', 'darkyellow': '#f8c040', 'lightyellow': '#e4de42'};
        var changeBackground = $('div.header_blue, div.reactie, section#adres, section#referenties_single div.pager');
        var changeColor = $('section#tevredenklanten h1, section#referenties_single h2.klant, section#referenties_single .wat_gedaan h2');
        var colorValue = $(this).attr('class');
        console.log(colorValue);
        //console.log(colorArr);
        console.log(colorArr.colorValue);
        //console.log(colorArr.red);
        changeBackground.animate({backgroundColor:colorArr.colorValue}, 600);
    });
}
```

Does anyone know what I have to do?

Comment: `colorArr` doesn't have a property `colorValue`, hence the undefined. You probably want to try `colorArr[colorValue]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

Comment: Gotta keep that one in mind as a good duplicate for every JavaScript question ever. :)

Answer (score 4):

Since `colorValue` is not the object key but it contains the key to be looked for you need to use `[]` notation instead of `.` notation

```
console.log(colorArr[colorValue]);
```

When you say `colorArr.colorValue` it looks for a key called `colorValue` in the object `colorArr` which does not exists thus it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Access your object using the bracket notation, when the property name is stored in another variable:

```
colorArr[ colorValue ]
```

When using the dot notation JavaScript searches for a property with the very name "colorValue", which is not present, and hence returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
colorArr[ colorValue ]
```

We can access the object values by passing the key

```
colorArr["greenyellow"]= it yields the corresponding result.
```